# Overlapping sliding windows in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I wrote the following code to create Overlapping Sliding Window in python and do some calculations in the each window. But I am not getting the correct output.

I am using Jupyter Notebook.

First I have stored the text file in the list. Then calculated the total number of C's and G's in each window. window size = 50kb  and increment= 10kb. 
The problem is that the code is giving output for only 5 windows and 0 for the rest of the windows. So have I made any mistake in the code for overlapping sliding window or counting?

```
char = []
with open('xyz.txt') as f:
   for line in f:
     line = line.strip()
     for ch in line:
        char.append(ch)

w_s = 50000 #window size
inc = 10000 #increment
x = 4215606
now = 1 #no. of windows
no_of_C = []
no_of_G = []
i = 0
for i in range (0,len(char)-w_s,i + inc):

  nC = 0
  nG = 0

  for j in range(i,w_s):
     if char[j] == 'C':
         nC = nC + 1
     elif char[j] == 'G':
         nG = nG + 1
  a = no_of_C.append(nC)
  b = no_of_G.append(nG)
  print(no_of_C)
  print(no_of_G)
```

I wrote this code without using any libraries but is there any other way to create overlapping sliding windows in python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Edited answer. Thank you Sonali.*

`for j in range(i,w_s):`
since you're doing a for-loop from i to w_s and i is 50000 and more after just a few iterations and w_s is set to 50000, from iteration 5 this for-loop won't run anything. :)

**Solution**
I believe if you change the line to:

`for j in range(i, i + w_s):`

Then you should get the results you want. :)

Comment: Your point 1 is not accurate. `range()` is not evaluated at each iteration. Since `i = 0` before the iteration, it basically does nothing, that line is equivalent to `for i in range(0, len(char) - w_s, inc):`.

Comment: @Sonali Happy to help :)